# How to match already-calculated means to the original data set?

Tags: sql, r

I am now learning R. I feel that there is a very easy succinct answer to my problem, but I am having trouble solving it myself.

I have a large data set. One column contains various 'categories'. I aggregated these categories to get the mean for each one. So, right now, my aggregated table looks like this:

Category  *_*_   Average

A  ***_*__*_*____**     a

B   ***_*__*_*____**  b

C   ***_*__*_*____**          c

etc...

I want now to take these average and combine it as another column onto my original data.
So, I want it to look something like this:

Categories ***_*____**     Averages

B  ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**  b

A_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**_a

B_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**_b

C_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**_c

B_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**_b

C_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**_c

In other words, I want to match each category with its corresponding mean. I have tried variations of merge(), match(), and different apply functions. The fact that my aggregated table is so much smaller than my original data is causing some problems.

Is there a specific function I can use for this simple problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `match` or `merge` can probably do it, .... but you need to provide a reproducible example in R code.

Comment: Perhaps, it would be helpful to use something like `ave(mydf$value, mydf$category, FUN = mean)` in your original dataframe and not `aggregate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In base R:

```
data <- data.frame(Category=c(rep("A",3), rep("B",4), rep("C",2)), Value=1:9)
> data
  Category Value
1        A     1
2        A     2
3        A     3
4        B     4
5        B     5
6        B     6
7        B     7
8        C     8
9        C     9

> avg <- lapply(split(data$Value, data$Category), mean)
$A
[1] 2

$B
[1] 5.5

$C
[1] 8.5

> data$Averages <- avg[data$Category]
> data
  Category Value Averages
1        A     1        2
2        A     2        2
3        A     3        2
4        B     4      5.5
5        B     5      5.5
6        B     6      5.5
7        B     7      5.5
8        C     8      8.5
9        C     9      8.5
```

You can use `plyr`, `data.table`, etc. more efficiently for larger datasets.

Comment: This is great; thank you so much! Does this method automatically ignore NA values? I had a few NA's for 'Category'.

Comment: @user3334684 - mean takes an optional parameter to ignore NAs. See `?mean` for details. You can simply add it to the `lapply` function above.

Comment: It actually ignores the `NA` values presently when it calculates the average. You could do something like `data$Category[is.na(data$Category)] <- "Q"` and then run the calculation. This would treat all `NA` categories as equivalent.

Comment: @arg3334684 If this answer worked for you, it would be great if you could "accept" it.

Comment: I do not see an 'accept' option. This is only my second day on stack overflow. Mind directing me to accepting your answer?

Comment: Hmm .. isn't there a tick mark below answer rating (up-down arrow with 0 in between) that turns green when clicked. Otherwise, no problem -- just seeking some reps. :)